# How do I sign Ubuntu Code of Conduct with specific OpenPGP key?

Tags: launchpad, gnupg, openpgp

I have four OpenPGP keys, I need to sign the [Ubuntu *Code of Conduct*](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/conduct) with a specific OpenPGP key. How do I make one of the OpenPGP key is default so I can sign the code with that key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Signing the Ubuntu Code of Conduct

The general signing procedure is described in [Ubuntu's GnuPG how-to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto#Signing_Data). It boils down to performing a clear-text signature of a text document:

```
gpg --clearsign UbuntuCodeofConduct-2.0.txt
```

## Selecting a Specific Key for Signing

To sign using a specific key, you need to tell GnuPG which one to use. From `man gpg`:

```
   --clearsign
          Make a clear text signature.  The content in a  clear  text
          signature is readable without any special software. OpenPGP
          software is only needed to  verify  the  signature.   Clear
          text signatures may modify end-of-line whitespace for plat-
          form independence and are not intended  to  be  reversible.
          The  key to be used for signing is chosen by default or can
          be set with the --local-user and --default-key options.

   [snip]

   --local-user name
   -u     Use  name  as  the  key to sign with. Note that this option
          overrides --default-key.
```

The changed clearsign command form above is:

```
gpg --local-user [key-id] --clearsign UbuntuCodeofConduct-2.0.txt
```

## Setting a Persistent Default Key

This just modifies the behavior for the current call of GnuPG. To set a *default* key (which can still be overridden using `--local-user`), set `default user [key-id]` in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` instead.